# Detecting presence (arrival/departure) with active RFID

Tags: jsp

I want to create a JSP Web Application to work with RFID device to manage attendance with the use of javaltk please help me to do that. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The Java LTK is an open source software project that enables RFID application development on readers that support LLRP. Although the Java LTK isn't an Impinj software product, it works very well with the Speedway Revolution reader. This post will show you how to create a Java LTK "Hello World" application that reads tags.

First, download the Java LTK from Sourceforge.

If you're using a Java IDE like Eclipse, the build process is handled for you. If you're using the command line, first compile:

`javac -cp ltkjava-1.0.0.6-with-dependencies.jar`

`HelloJavaLtkMain.java HelloJavaLtk.java`

Then run:

```
 java -cp :ltkjava-1.0.0.6-with-dependencies.jar
```

Make sure the .jar file is in your [CLASSPATH.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29)
Create a new class that implements the LLRPEndpoint interface. This class will contain all of our Java LTK code.

Finally, we need an application class and Main function to start up our program. Make sure to change the reader hostname when you call the run function (highlighted below).

```
public class HelloJavaLtkMain{
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    HelloJavaLtk app = new HelloJavaLtk();

    System.out.println("Starting reader.");
    app.run("SpeedwayR-10-2E-63");
    Thread.sleep(30000);
    System.out.println("Stopping reader.");
    app.stop();
    System.out.println("Exiting application.");
    System.exit(0);
}}
```

Comment: Hello, I know it's a bit too late, but do you know how can I get this "SpeedwayR-10-2E-63" code? I have an Impinj RS500.